# How to hide error message when click on other input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have code that shows msg when we write 20 in text input :

link of code for test : https://jsfiddle.net/wdqvkjnu/

```
$(function() {
    var money = 20;
$("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
    var input = $(this);

    // remove possible existing message
    if( input.next().is("h5") )
        input.next().remove();

    // show message
    if( input.val() === money.toString() )
        input.after("<h5>Thank You</h5>");
});
```

});
what I want to add:

1> red color for the error

2>when I click on other input the message disapear

AnyOne can help ??

Comment: add a class to the error message say : `input-error-message` and remove them as `document.querySelectorAll('.input-error-message').forEach(d => d.remove());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:-

```js
$(function() {
  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  var money = 20;

  $("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
    var input = $(this);

    // remove possible existing message
    document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", function() {
      message.textContent = "";
    }));

    // show message
    if (input.val() === money.toString()) {
      message.style.color = "green";
      message.textContent = "Thank You ";
    }

    if (input.val() !== money.toString()) {
      message.style.color = "red";
      message.textContent = "Error: Enter a valid number ";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
Input 1: <input id="nominal" type="text" /> 
Input 2: <input id="nom" type="text" />
<h5 id="message"></h5>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pratical solution:

```
$(function() {
var money = 20;
  $("#nom").on("click", function() {
    $("#nominal").val('');
     $(".error").remove();
    });
$("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
    var input = $(this);

    // remove possible existing message
    if( input.next().is("h5") )
        input.next().remove();

    // show message
    if( input.val() === money.toString() )
        input.after("<h5>Thank You</h5>");
        
           
     if( input.val() !== money.toString() )
     input.after("<h5 class='error' style='color:red;''>Error!</h5>");
});
});
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```html
<div>
<input id="nominal" type="text" />
<input id="nom" type="text" />
</div>
```

```js
 $(function() {
  var money = 20;

  $("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
    var input = $(this);
/*
for red color you can add style attribute or add css class 
*/
    if (input.val() === money.toString())
      input.after("<h5 style='color:#f00'>Thank You</h5>");
  });

/*
for remove error massage if exist use another listner 
*/

  $("#nominal,#nom").on("change keyup", function() {
    if ($(this).val() != money.toString())
      $(this).parent().find('h5').remove();
  })

});
```